# Getting unspecified data while fetching data using mongoose find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, typescript, mongoose

Here is my code

```
fetchAll(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.find({})
        .exec((err: any, res: any) => {
            if(err){
                reject(new Error("No heroes found"));
            }else{
                resolve(res);
                console.log(res);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

I am calling above method from controller using,

```
getUsers():Promise<IUser[]> {
        return this.userService.fetchAll().then((users) => {
           return users;
        }).catch((err) => {
            debug(`ERROR:${module}:getHeroById`)(err);
            throw new NotFoundError(err.message);
        });
    }
```

While accessing api end point i am getting below result which contain some unwanted data.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @drinchev I need only _doc instead of displaying all other data in my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to only render the `dataValues` of your instance, you can use [`toJSON()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON) method of mongoose.

Your retrieve query should look like :

```
fetchAll(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.find({})
        .exec((err: any, res: any) => {
            if(err){
                reject(new Error("No heroes found"));
            }else{
                users = res.map( user => user.toJSON() );
                resolve(users);
                console.log(users);
            }
        })
    });
}
```